# Project/Task tracking tool with notifications

Tags: project-management, tracking, agile-project-management

I am looking for a particular project/task tracking tool with :

1. Ability to define hierarchy of task. Like Project -> Task -> Sub-task etc.
2. Ability to assign owner.
3. Status level like NotStarted, Inprogress, Impeded, Complete
4. Notification based i.e. any change should be notified through an email or RSS feed.
5. Open source

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.redmine.org/ is what you're looking for. 
I have used it extensively and it works well.

`"Project -> Task -> Sub-task"` is more like `"Project -> Sub-Project -> Task"`

But this is a good thing.

Comment: Thanks Lionel. I have started looking into this tool. Does this tool also provided some notification mechanism for cases like adding some task, update in task etc ?

Comment: yes, it does, you need to give it a email account (we used gmail). I didn't do it myself but the dev who did didn't complain about the setup, it was quite straighforward. (see http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/EmailConfiguration).

Comment: Thanks Lionel, hope this tool helps my team.